# Data binding not working correctly after configuration changed on kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a tab bar that contains a Nested ScrollView. When I scroll down, if I click the tab bar it has to send me on top of View, this works correctly all the time except the time that i change the theme. If I change the theme it will not sent me on top of view.

I tried testing it with debug, it calls the function but it does not go to top. To test the problem i tried to set margins when I click it but that does not work either. My doubts are that the binding its not correct but don't know how to fix it?
This is on my fragment

```
  override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_community, container)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initAdapters(savedInstanceState)
        initBaseFunctions()
    }
override fun onClickTab() {
        if (::binding.isInitialized){
            binding.recyclerViewPosts.requestLayout()
            binding.recyclerViewPosts.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
        }
    }
```

On my activity that contains tab bar :

```
        if (position !in navStateViewModel.tabBarFragments.indices) return false
        return if (binding.fragmentViewPager.currentItem == position) {
            // is not community fragment
            if (position != 0) {
                navStateViewModel.communityFragment.value.pauseCurrentVideo(clearVid = true)
            }
            // is the same fragment, scroll to top
            (navStateViewModel.tabBarFragments[position].value as? TabClickListener)?.onClickTab()
            false
        } else {
            val shouldScroll = abs(position - binding.fragmentViewPager.currentItem) < 3
            // pause video
            navStateViewModel.communityFragment.value.pauseCurrentVideo()
            binding.fragmentViewPager.setCurrentItem(position, shouldScroll)
            true
        }
    }
```